# What is the MetaMask workaround if Web3 is deprecated

Tags: web3js, metamask

While using MetaMask, adding Web3 to a Javascript program displays the following message in the Chrome console:
"MetaMask: web3 will be deprecated in the near future in favor of the ethereumProvider"

Should I continue creating a website that requires MetaMask, if Web3 will be deprecated in the near future?

Is there a workaround, or is there another extension that allows Javascript to interact with Ethereum in the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the useless warning message. The path forward for now is to always use `web3.currentProvider`. The web3 global will still exist, it simply won't have any methods on it, so as long as you're following [our guide on detecting and initializing your own web3](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check), you should be fine.

Comment: Please confirm that if I only use the web3 object created by "window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)", then my code will not become useless.

Comment: As long as you imported that Web3 class, and are including it with your own code. Don't rely on an injected Web3 class, just the web3.currentProvider object.

Comment: Please confirm that I don't have to do anything other than have the user logged into MetaMask, and create a web3 object in Javascript with the following command: "window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)". Confirm that I don't have to import any other classes, or do anything else.

Comment: I can't confirm that. I just said you need to import your own Web3 instance, or equivalent abstaction library, like ethjs.

Comment: Please indicate where the specific instructions can be found to "import your own Web3 instance, or equivalent abstaction library". In your first response to this issue, you said "as long as you're following our guide, you should be fine". The guide that you provided a link to did not indicate that anything else needs to be downloaded or installed. You indicated that it was a "useless warning message". Now your inferring that my code will stop working if I don't perform some actions that are not documented anywhere. So please provide specific instructions, and not just a vague description.

Comment: I saw this right before going to sleep. I will try to write a good guide for this soon.

Comment: I've summarized this issue in a new FAQ article here, I'll migrate it to our knowledge base soon:

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md

Comment: "This document may be outdated"

Comment: Here's a more recent doc, which also includes the new window.ethereum object: https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/API_Reference/Ethereum_Provider

Answer (score 3):

DanF's answer is the correct answer, and should be accepted, but looking at the comments, I think there's some valuable context that might be missing, that I can add.

A typical dapp consists of a number of layers, which don't need to know much about the layers above or below them. Most dapps will use a library that provides a nice interface to the ethereum blockchain, such as Web3, truffle-contract or EthJS (although this is optional, and it's perfectly possible to write a dapp that doesn't use any of these libraries, and just uses lower-level interfaces). These libraries don't typically have the ability to access the blockchain directly (this is a slight lie - they often have helpers for local development, but it's close enough for most purposes), so need to have a low-level "provider" made available, that gives them access to the blockchain. MetaMask is such a provider.

In the early days, most dapp browsers (including MetaMask, Mist and Parity) worked by making a copy of Web3 available to dapps (by adding a `web3` object to `window`), rather than making this provider available directly. Dapps that wanted to use other libraries, so needed to get at the underlying provider, would typically get hold of it with `window.web3.currentProvider`.

As time's gone on, it's become clear that even if you intend to use Web3 as your library of choice, it's a good idea to import Web3 into your dapp yourself (the same way you'd import any other library - Webpack or Parcel or SystemJS or Bower or plain ol' script tags pointing to a CDN), and initialise it with the provider from `window.web3.currentProvider`. This way, you always know what version of Web3 you're using, and aren't surprised by breaking API changes.

But if dapps are only using `window.web3` to get at `window.web3.currentProvider`, then what's the point in including the rest of Web3 in `window.web3`? Not much. So MetaMask is planning (at some point) to change `window.web3` from being a full copy of Web3, to just being a stub that provides `currentProvider`.

If you're still using the copy of Web3 provided by `window.web3` at that point, then your code will no longer work. However, if you follow [the instructions that DanF linked to](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md) to obtain a provider, and then follow the instructions for your library of choice from there on out, then it will work with current and future versions of MetaMask (as well as Parity and Mist, which I believe follow the same convention).

Comment: Amazing that no one provided SPECIFIC INSTRUCTIONS how to download the Web3 javascript include files. This post has received nothing but ambiguous answers with links to websites that require that you download a bunch of risky include files.

Comment: Please provide a SIMPLE CONCISE explanation how to download just the necessary Javascript files, so MetaMask users won't have to worry that "at that point, your code will no longer work.". I sent an email to all the authors of MetaMask last week, and did not receive a single response. Dan F's domain was not even working. MetaMask seems like a risky extension to use.

Comment: I didn't add those instructions deliberately, since most front-end projects I've worked on use a build tool like Webpack, Parcel, or Bower, so it would do more harm than good to provide instructions that wouldn't apply to everyone. But the simplest thing you could possibly do is to download the minified version of Web3 from https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/raw/0.19.0/dist/web3.min.js, and add it to your HTML file with `<script src="web3.min.js"></script>`. If you're using a build tool, add the web3 module to your project in whatever way you would normally add a module.

Comment: Also, just to respond to your assertion that "MetaMask seems like a risky extension to use", note that all the Ethereum dapp browsers I know of work in precisely the same way. If you want to integrate with an alternative dapp browser, the way you do this is exactly the same. The only exception to this would be if you wanted to use infura.io, and skip the dapp browser entirely, but this is more work, and has security implications that you need to understand before you proceed any further (make sure you understand how the recent EtherDelta hack worked, before you go down that road).

Comment: James, thank you for your informative response. It is nice to finally have the web3 include file, in case MetaMask should suddenly require that it is added (which would cause many MetaMask users to have their scripts immediately fail).

Comment: James, I googled 'etherdelta hack infura' and couldn't find any connection, other than the mention that MetaMask apparently uses Infura to connect to Ethereum. Please let me know if there is any reason to distrust Infura. Thanks!

Comment: @Tester There's no reason to distrust Infura. The connection to the EtherDelta hack is more subtle. EtherDelta have two operating modes: if you've got MetaMask or similar, it'll use that, if not, it'll use a built-in in-browser wallet that talks to Infura directly. They got their DNS record hacked, and someone put up a fake version of the site that stole private keys. However, the attackers only got the private key for the in-browser-wallet users.

Comment: The reason they were able to do this, is that the malicious code had exactly the same privileges as the in-browser wallet, so could read all its data, including the private keys. Whereas because MetaMask is a browser extension, web sites (even malicious ones) can't access any of its internal data - the worst a malicious site can do is ask you to sign a transaction.

Answer (score -4):

To answer my own question, it appears that **you should NOT create a website that requires MetaMask**.

The previous answerer (who apparently is the creator of MetaMask) contradicted himself. First, he said "Sorry for the useless warning message ... you should be fine". Then, after I relied on this answer and spent the entire weekend creating a website around the MetaMask extension, he said (in the comments above) "you need to import your own Web3 instance, or equivalent abstaction library, like ethjs". None of the MetaMask documentation describes how to do this.

Without specific, unambiguous instructions, I am very reluctant to release a website that could potentially have millions of dollars in transactions.

Comment: MetaMask is implementing the foundation-backed Ethereum provider protocol, to the fullest extent possible. The lack of documentation you see for MetaMask is really global to the space, because it's young and moving fast.

Comment: While I am a developer on MetaMask, I'm not the only one, I didn't author that warning, I tried to help you.  I've opened an issue for adding better docs around this, we'll try to add them soon. https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2014

Comment: Please provide specific answers to these questions: 1. What date will MetaMask fail to work with the current instructions (without downloading an additional JS include file). 2. What JS include file needs to be included for MetaMask to work after that date, and what is its download URL. 3. Will the "window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)" command work the same after including this new JS file. 4. Will all other instructions in your documentation work as described after including this new JS file. 5. Have you personally tested the answers given. 6. Are there any other caveats.

Comment: 1. We do not have a firm deprecation date, we are waiting on web3 1.0 to be final, and so this warning maybe should not have been shown yet. 2. You don't need to include any JS file at all, the ethereumProvider provides all the functionality of web3, however it is not a user-friendly API (provider.sendAsync), nor is it well documented, and so most people will choose to import an abstraction like web3 or ethjs. 3. If you import the same version of Web3, yes. 4. Yes. 5. Yes. 6. I'll be writing an article for this soon.

Comment: Your statement "You don't need to include any JS file at all" contradicted your previous reply  "you need to import your own Web3 instance". Which is it? If I am better off importing a JS file, then please provide its download URL and confirm that you have tested it and that all existing code will work with it. If there is no need to import a JS file, then please change your reply when I asked "Please confirm that I don't have to do anything other than have the user logged into MetaMask, and create a web3 object in Javascript." Please give me a straight answer, its either one or the other.

Comment: I have been perfectly straight with you the entire time:

IF you want to use the Web3 abstraction, you *will eventually* need to import it yourself. You can download it here:
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/

IF you do not care to use the web3 abstraction, you do not need to import any JS at all! You can use the provider API directly. It mirrors the Ethereum RPC provider spec, as described in this article I composed this morning and linked to you in the other thread on this question:
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md