# web3.js or eth.js?

Tags: web3js, ethjs

After receiving the warning:

> MetaMask: web3 will be deprecated in the near future in favor of the
>   ethereumProvider

I attempted to use [eth.js](https://github.com/ethjs)

But I am not convinced that it is production ready. Especially when they still have **We are aiming for early January 2017 for production** use as a goal.

It seems to be working for me, but I am not sure if I should continue with it other than to help with testing.

Any thoughts?

The warning seems to be pointless according to this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25651/what-is-the-metamask-workaround-if-web3-is-deprecated)

Comment: You also have [ether.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js).

Comment: yayyy, and is https://ethereumjs.github.io/ something different as well.
Great to see these projects on the go, just hope there is is not confusion as to which one.